# Is it a ladybird?

Tags: insects

I found this near my tomato plants. Is it a ladybird?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the general shape, colour and patterning, it looks like a Ladybird of some sort, but unfortunately, the focus of the picture is best on the woody stem and somewhat out of focus on the insect, so its hard to be 100% on ID.

Comment: Sure looks like one. To go way out on a limb here but not as an answer because of the issues mentioned by Bamboo - I think it could be Cheilomenes sexmaculata, the "Indian wave striped ladybug".  I don't think there are any harmful ones on tomatoes (like the Mexican bean beetle is to beans).  So it's likely eating aphids and other pests.  Good thing.

Comment: Rodolia cardinalis is another possible - it's been introduced as a biological control here in the US for Citrus, and I know from your other posts you have citrus plants. They were introduced to India as well.

Comment: Oh, I should say there are many species of ladybird beetles and these are pretty wild guesses.